# Split String by +-/* and keep all other special characters

Tags: java, regex

Hey guys I am trying to split a string that is a mathematical expression.

For example - 1.1234-345+43/23.546*34
I want to split by -+/* and keep all numbers.

I have tried this:

```
String[] newString = "242342.4242+424-32.545".split("[+-//*]");
```

But it does not work, it also splits by the . and it gives me 5 numbers in the array in the end, and it should give me 3 numbers.

The new string should look like this:

```
newString[0] = 242342.4242
newstring[1] = 424
newString[2] = 32.545
```

Comment: Because it’s a range.

Comment: Try this- `String[] newString = "242342.4242+424-32.545".split("[-+*/]");`

Comment: A more canonical duplicate target is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333325.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] newString = "242342.4242+424-32.545".split("[-+*/]");
        for (String s : newString)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should consider that some of the characters in your regular expression string are reserved for use by the Java Regex facility.  In order to use these characters as delimiters, they would need to be escaped.

Comment: @scottb But the code runs without any errors and gives the desired output. Do check it.

Comment: downvotes for correct answer! great!

Comment: @scottb.  Are you the person who downvote us? What was in your mind?

Comment: I did not downvote.  The Regex documentation states that characters which are reserved by the Regex facility should be escaped if the intent is to use them as literals.  If this implementation currently works, it needn't continue to work if the Regex implementation changes.  I refer you to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html

Comment: @scottb: But CrakC using [ ] so no need escaped. I think CrakC is correct and the fact is his code has no runtime error and produces correct result.

Comment: @Loc: if you mean to say that *"Regex metacharacters that appear within brackets, i.e. within a character class literal, do not need to be escaped when used as literal characters in the character class"* ... then this is incorrect.  Moreover, the specification or contract of an API has weight.  Even if disregarding an API's contract leads to desired results, this makes a program's correctness dependent upon an implementation detail which can change at any time.  In other words, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @scottb Alright so can you show me some cases where the above code would turn ambiguous?

Comment: @scottb So according to the regex documentation, `"[-+*/]"` should be `"\\Q-+*/\\E"`? But the documentation has no mention about the usage of `"[]"` like the way I have used it. Then there should be some input for which the above code would produce a wrong output. Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using | in pattern
        // \\ for special character

        String[] newString = "242342.4242+424-32.545".split("\\+|-|\\*"); // +|-|*
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newString));

        // Output

        // [242342.4242, 424, 32.545]

        // In the real world. You need to handle Space too
        // so using this pattern
        // \\s*(\\+|-|\\*)\\s*

        String[] newString2 = "242342.4242 + 424 - 32.545".split("\\s*(\\+|-|\\*)\\s*");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newString2));

        // Output

        // [242342.4242, 424, 32.545] - No spaces

    }
```

Comment: Same here. Downvote for awesome answer. Haha

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am using the other slash and I am not that familiar with ReGeX so I will accept CrankC's answer as it is much more simpler than yours, but I thank you for your effort!

Comment: upvote for your approach :)