# Python regex for infix calculator

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to catch...

```
( ) + - * /
```

OR

numbers in the following two formats...

```
xxx.xxx
```

IE 3.14159

```
xxx
```

IE 42

I have...

```
re.findall('[+-/*//()]|\d+(\.\d+)?', noWhitespaces)
```

The following expression ...

```
(2.0 + 2.0) / 1
```

... is generating ...

```
['', '.0', '', '.0', '', '', '']
```

and I don't know why.

I had...

```
re.findall('[+-/*//()]|\d+\.\d+', noWhitespaces)
```

Which worked for numbers in the `xxx.xxx` format IE `2.0` and the operators but not numbers in the `xxx` format, IE `1`.

EDIT: The exact code...

```
noWhitespaces = re.sub(r'\s+', '', s)
print(noWhitespaces)
tokens = re.findall(r'[-+/*//()]|\d+(\.\d+)?', noWhitespaces)
print(tokens)
```

Comment: Please put the `-` at the beginning or end of the character class. Otherwise it’ll be seen as a _range_ of characters from `+` to `/` which includes `,`, `-` and `.`. That’s something you would’ve seen immediately had you used [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to only allow alphanumeric, comma, hyphen, underscore and semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333325/regex-to-only-allow-alphanumeric-comma-hyphen-underscore-and-semicolon)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing group with findall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the second dot part as optional in `\d+\.\d+`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(2.0 + 2.0) / 1'
>>> re.findall(r'[-+/*()]|\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
['(', '2.0', '+', '2.0', ')', '/', '1']
```

Note that you need to make the capturing group as non-capturing group, since `findall` should give the first preference to captures. That's why you got `.0` in the output ie, the string captured by the capturing group.

Comment: I added the other regex code. It's really not working for me

Comment: make the capturing group as non-capturing group.