# Validate encoded URI against unencoded characters in PHP using regex

Tags: php, regex, validation

I encode user input URLs using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description), it encodes everything but these characters: `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

I tested it by encoding this string:

```
https://example.com/-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=$%^%22{}|<>
```

and it returned

`https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F-._~%3A%2F%3F%23%5B%5D%40!%24%26'()*%2B%2C%3B%3D%24%25%5E%2522%7B%7D%7C%253C%253E`

which additionally contains `%`. I wonder if it can include anything else I missed?

So I would like to test if the string passed to PHP has any unencoded characters, other than

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) %
```

I am trying to test against `/^[a-zA-Z0-9%.-_~!'()*]+$/g` using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but it passes for a string such as `abc;<>`. Here is [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hi4CgJ/1/) with it. What am I doing wrong?

Just a note, I am not trying to validate the format of URL, just to see if the user is not trying to slip in anything funny around the javascript validator or see if the javascript validator is not broken. Here is a sketch of what I am trying to defend the system against:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that URL encoding has anything to do with SQL validation.  If you want to prevent SQL injection attacks, you'll have to do something like use a prepared statement in your server side PHP script, or sterilize the inputs in PHP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using the Laravel framework for PDOs. They say it is safe, but I still don't feel comfortable letting users post just anything using it. I'd like some constraints just to narrow the scope of a problem so I can try to wrap my head around it

Comment: Any driver can be SQL injected, PDO alone does nothing to prevent SQL injections. You need to parameterize the queries. (Unrelated but that regex won't run in PHP, there is no `g` modifier)

Comment: @user3783243 I am using [this feature of laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#introduction) and I just hope it works as it says it does because I really feel like my skills are insufficient to set it all up manually

Comment: There are multiple examples on that page and the note, `Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection vulnerabilities.` shows some uses are insecure. I'd say using a regex to validate SQL will get you injected a majority of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to only allow alphanumeric, comma, hyphen, underscore and semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333325/regex-to-only-allow-alphanumeric-comma-hyphen-underscore-and-semicolon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your regex you have `.-_` which is interpreted as any character between `.` (char 46) and `_` (char 95). You can see that in the explanation on your regex101 link. This includes the `<` and `>` characters which is why your pattern matches. To fix it, add a `\` in front of the `-` to ensure it is treated as a literal `-` i.e. change your regex to

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9%.\-_~!'()*]+$
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! It seems like I still need more work on the queries side, but that's the next step I guess

Comment: @Nick, `.` should be `\.` else it also be interpreted as any character I presume.

Comment: @vivek_23 not inside `[]`

Answer (score 1):

The `encodeURIComponent()` encodes all nonalphanumeric characters. And another `encodeURI()` does not encode special characters however converts spaces into `%20`.

The `encodeURI()` is designed to work on full URI whereas `encodeURIComponent()` is designed to work on a segment of a URI.

I always use `encodeURIComponent()` to the value to make the data safe and secure in my AJAX requests.